# Error when trying to query Mongodb database after adding new field (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection called `conversation_trees` and it was working fine, then I wanted to add a new field into it but when I did I started getting the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in MongoDB.Bson.dll

My code:

```
public List<Node> FindRoot()
{
    List<Node> results = collection.Find(x => x.parents.Length == 0).ToList();
    results.Count();
    return results;
}


[Serializable]
[BsonNoId]
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Node
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string node_Id { get; set; }
    public string[] parents { get; set; }
    public string[] children { get; set; }
    public string node_type { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public bool user_input { get; set; }
    public string ar { get; set; }
}
```

Originally I had copied over all document from a remote server to a new cosmosdb instance and it worked fine, but adding any fields myself will break it.

I originally had node_Id (previously just Id), parents and children as ObjectId's and [BsonId], [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)], [BsonNoId] and [BsonIgnoreExtraElements] are all things I added afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Are your added filed is Nullable? MongoDB has no information about data structure.

- Reduce your query. Just try to select only "old" field. Still you have this error?
- Map your added fileds to nullable variable types, then if filed has no value it will set member to null.